# How to display subfolders by numerical order in python

Tags: python, subdirectory

I have folders named by numbers, and  want to sort them by a numerical order, as shown in the code bellow:

```
f = os.walk(dataset_dir )
for subdir, dirs, files in enumerate(sorted(f), start=1):
    display(subdir)
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Comment: enumerate gives two values

Comment: please, show us the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can unpack in the following manner:

```
for i, (subdir, dirs, files) in enumerate(sorted(f), start=1):
```

Alternatively:

```
for i, entry in enumerate(sorted(f), start=1):
    subdir, dirs, files = entry
```

Comment: or, closer to what OP is doing: `for _ , (subdir, dirs, files) in enumerate(....)` ?

Comment: @AdrianShum In that case, enumerate isn't even needed.

Comment: I agree, that's also what I felt confused when I first read OP's code...